# Maybe an error in "beginning php and mysql"

Tags: php, require

I'm reading your book *beginning php and mysql* , and I find an error.
In chapter 3, page 111:

```
For instance, if require() is placed within an
if statement that evaluates to false, the file would be included anyway.
```

But I test this with my code. It's not true.
b.php

```
<?php
if(false)
{
     require "a.php";
}
?>
```

a.php

```
<?php
echo "this is a.php<br>"
?>
```

I run the b.php. Nothing is on the page.

My php version is 5.4.7. So does the book say wrong?

Comment: Is that really _our_ book? I don't think I had anything to do with writing it. :)

Comment: it looks like you are missing a `;` at the end of `echo`.

Comment: @Class `echo "this is a.php<br>"` It will still echo out, just as long as there isn't another echo'ed line under that. If there are 2 echo'ed lines on two seperate lines, then the first echo'ed line needs a semi-colon, and not the last. However if the OP does an `include`, then yes like you said, will need a semi-colon. It's always best to use them, either way. (I always do).

Comment: Ah you may be right, however if you used `if(!false)` then you will get your echo after all ;-)

Comment: If that's what the book said, then get your money back ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As we see `if` statement works over boolean parameter as the condition shall state `TRUE` or `FALSE` if its already false then it will head to else part of statement.

Here the crisp is that File is included but due to `if(false)` no result will be shown.